# map and reduce is getting failed when running using hadoop streaming command

Tags: python, hadoop

My python mapper and reducer code is running fine when i m running with out hadoop streaming command

```
hadoop fs -cat /user/root/myinput/testfile3_node.csv | ./mapper_1.py | sort | ./reducer_1.py
```

where as when i am running the code using hadoop streaming command then it fails

```
hadoop jar /usr/iop/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-streaming.jar -mapper ./mapper_1.py -reducer ./reducer_1.py -file ./mapper_1.py -file ./reducer_1.py -input /user/root/myinput/testfile3.csv -output /user/root/myoutput/indexing_output1
```

Outputs:

[Screenshot of simple command_running.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZYfk.png)
[Screenshot of Hadoop streaming jar command.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2ZNR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try without ./ on the -mapper and -reducer parameters(make sure you are in the right directory) and also there is no need fot the -files:

```
hadoop  jar /usr/iop/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-streaming.jar \
    -mapper mapper_1.py \
    -reducer reducer_1.py \
-input /user/root/myinput/testfile3.csv -output /user/root/myoutput/indexing_output1
```

Here is the Apache Hadoop docs:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html

Comment: Which version of hadoop are running? I use that on 1.2.1 and it works fine.